# Yeoman plugin Maven goal execution error on Windows

Tags: node.js, maven-3, yeoman

While installing a node project through Maven-yeoman plugin I am  getting this issue(in windows+eclipse) environment. I am doing clean install from Maven.

Below is stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.4:build (default) on project myapp-web: Error during : cmd /c grunt buil
olor: Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.4:build (default) on p
pf-web: Error during : cmd /c grunt build --no-color
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during : cmd /c grunt build --no-color
        at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:127)
        at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.logAndExecuteCommand(YeomanMojo.java:108)
        at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.build(YeomanMojo.java:97)
        at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.execute(YeomanMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
        at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:125)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: To be clean you should read the error message `Error during : cmd /c grunt build --no-color` first and second: `Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6)` ? Apart from that if you run this from inside Eclipse this is not Maven...if you like to check it just use it from plain command line....

Comment: I have tried running maven install outside eclipse as well from command line, which is resulting in same error.

Comment: So then the command is the problem which means `grunt` have you checked to run grunt directly instead of via this maven plugin...